# how to set a form that save the info in database with joomla?

Tags: joomla

Ive been trying to create a form that save the info in my database... sounds pretty easy but I have messy documentation (or I am not so smart), I just want to send some parameters on my submit, in the other side catch them and save some info at the database....

**So, I did this:**

in my *`component/views/myview/tmpl/default.php`* I wrote this:

```
<form action="index.php">
<input type="submit" value="test" />
</form>
```

Then, I went to my file `view.html.php` on `/mycomponent/view/component/view.html` and I do this:

```
$this->get('SaveClient');
```

and in my model I did this (only for trying):

```
public function getSaveClient(){

  $query ="
      Insert into client ( `id_client` ,`test`)
      VALUES 
      (NULL , '1')
  ";
  $db = & JFactory::getDBO();
  $db->Execute($query);
}
```

But still.. doesnt work, any idea how to make it work??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined the table name correctly. It should be `#__tablename`. Once you have tried this and it still doesn't work, try using the following code below instead.

```
public function getSaveClient($test){ 
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $data = new stdClass();
    $data->id_client = null;
    $data->test = $test;
    $db->insertObject( '#__tablename', $data, 'id_client' );  
}
```

Comment: How can I call the model sending an argument? :-s as I saw in some docs is not possible, as I saw in others it is... Ive tried but still.. nothing, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

your layout default.php form like

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_example&view=example&layout=default'); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm">
<input size="60" type="text" name="settings[key]" id="settings[key]" value="<?php echo (isset ($this->settings ['key']) ? htmlspecialchars ($this->settings ['key']) : ''); ?>" />
// More html entites.
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
</form>
```

Your view.html.php
//your class

```
public function display ($tpl = null)
    {
        $document = &JFactory::getDocument ();
        $document->addStyleSheet ('components/com_example/assets/css/example.css');

        $model = &$this->getModel ();
        $this->settings = $model->getSettings ();
        $this->form = $this->get ('Form');
        $this->addToolbar ();
        parent::display ($tpl);
    }
```

Your model 
your model class

```
public function saveSettings ()
    {
        //Get database handle
        $db = $this->getDbo ();
        $api_settings = array();
        $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
        //Read Settings
        $settings = JRequest::getVar ('settings');
                //Insert new settings
          foreach ($settings as $k => $v)
          {

             $sql = "INSERT INTO #__yourtable ( setting, value )" . " VALUES ( " . $db->Quote ($k) . ", " . $db->Quote ($v) . " )";
            $db->setQuery ($sql);
            $db->query ();
          }
              }
```